# Mapping cylinder is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

> If $f:X\to Y$ is a map between Hausdorff spaces, then $M_f$ and $C_f$ are Hausdorff. Here, $M_f$ and $C_f$ are mapping cyliner and mapping cone i.e. $M_f = X\times I\sqcup Y/(x,0)\sim f(x)$ for $x\in X$ and $C_f = M_f/(X\times\{1\})$

I first tried to prove $M_f$ is $T_2$. Before, as $X$ and $Y$ are $T_2$, $X\times I\sqcup Y$ is $T_2$. Now let $[x],[y]\in M_f$ such that $[x]\neq[y]$. Then $x\neq y$ so we can find open nbds $U,V$ of $x,y$ in $X\times I\sqcup Y$ respectively such that $U\cap V = \emptyset$. I have no idea how to get further. Could you give any hint?

Comment: Wha are $M_f$ and $C_f$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I just edit the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: distinguish cases.
The classes in $M_f$ can be singletons, for most points this is the case, i.e. all $[(x,t)]$ where $t \neq 0$ are their own class.

If we have the class of $(x,0)$: this is a non-trivial class as $(x,0) \sim f(x)$ by definition, and the class becomes $(f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}] \times \{0\}) \cup \{f(x)\}$: it will also
contain all $(x',0)$ where $f(x')=f(x)$, as these are forced to be in the same class via transivity and the connecting $f(x)$.

How would you separate the points $\{(x,t)\}$ and $(f^{-1}[\{f(p)\}] \times \{0\}) \cup \{f(p)\}$ in $M_f$? The former has a saturared neighbourhood $X \times (a,1)$ in $X \times I \sqcup Y$ for some $0 <a < t$, while for the latter we can use the saturated neighbourhood $Y \sqcup X \times [0,a)$ in that same space. The quotient images of these disjoint saturated open sets are still disjoint (general fact) and as required.

A little more thougth is required to separate $(f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}] \times \{0\}) \cup \{f(x)\}$ and $(f^{-1}[\{f(x')\}] \times \{0\}) \cup \{f(x')\}$ for distinct $x,x'$ in $X$ with $f(x) \neq f(x')$; here you must use the Hausdorffness of $X$ and $Y$ really.

The class of some $y \in Y$ is either of the same form as the previous case, namely $\{y\} \cup (f^{-1}[\{y\}])\times \{0\}$ if $y\in f[X]$, or else just $\{y\}$.

I'll leave you to puzzle out the details, but you do need to go in such case by case detail and realise what the classes actually *are* as subsets of the sum.

Comment: Let me ask just one thing. Once we consider all cases of points in $X\times I$ in $M_f$, we actually don't need to care about the case when the point is in $Y$ right? Because all nontrivial cases are handled already considering $X\times I$

Comment: @love_sodam some points in $Y$ are not related to points elsewhere. So such points need to be considered.

Comment: You mean points in $f(X)$. But It's already considered $[(x,0)]$

Comment: Ah you mean separation of points in $f(X)$ and $Y\setminus f(X)$?

Comment: @love_sodam but points not in $fX]$ are alone.

Comment: Yes but if $f(x)\neq f(x')\in f(X)$, then this separation is same as the separation of $[(x,0)]$ and $[(x',0)]$ in $M_f$ isn't it?

Comment: @love_sodam You need to explicitly consider all cases, so this one too.

Comment: Yes but I don't understand the point of separating points in $f(X)$. We can Identify the points in $f(X)$ and points in $X\times\{0\}$ in $M_f$